# Enforcing uniqueness of a model in has_many though

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `User` model, which has_many `Dish` through `Recommendation`. I would like to enforce uniqueness of `Dish`, as well as uniqueness of `Recommendation`.

How should I go about this in `ActiveRecord`?

In my `dish.rb`:

```
validate_uniqueness_of :dish_name
```

What I would like to have is: when an user recommends a dish, create a new dish if it does not exist, then create recommendation. If the dish already exists, then just create recommendation and point to existing dish.

Do I need to handle these situations manually (i.e., checking existence of `dish` in controller), or ActiveRecord has a way to handle it internally?

Update:
`validate_uniqueness_of :dish_name` only checks and return error message if the `dish` was created there. It probably won't create new `recommendation` that points to existing `dish`.

Comment: with the `validate_uniqueness_of :dish_name` the ActiveRecord will validate it and you don't have to worry about getting two dishes with the exact same name in your `dish` table. And if your attribute's name is `name` then put it like `:name` in the validation. If its really called `dish_name` then leave it as you wrote it.

Comment: Zippie: please check my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always [`.find_or_create_by_<attribute>`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Dynamic+attribute-based+finders) to find the dish to begin with

Comment: Just FYI: `find_or_create_by` will be deprecated in Rails 4. The new syntax is `where(attribute: '...').first_or_create`. See the Deprecated Finders section in http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: Good to know. Also, I think that is much cleaner than find_or_create

Answer (score 1):

As I see, more than one user can recommend the same dish.

Your models should look like:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :recommendations
has_many :dishes, :through => :recommendations
end

Class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :recommendations
has_many :users, :through => :recommendations
end
```

So your Recommendations table in database should have two columns (beside it's id and timestamps) called `user_id` and `dish_id` . To validate that a user doesn't recommend
the same dish twice, do:

```
Class Recommendations < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :dish
belongs_to :user
validates_uniqueness_of :dish_id, :scope => :user_id
end
```

And i didn't know about the `.find_or_create_by` method that Dan recommended, so definetly try to use something like that.

Hope i helped :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed answer, though I knew this part.

Comment: Oh, ok sorry i was just writing it down to make sure that i'm on the same page with your associations and was kinda writing it so you can see how to validate the uniqueness of the recommendations table :)
Hope you will get a good answer :)

Comment: Thanks Zippie. I just learned about validating with :scope (my first version of the question got it wrong :))